# Display one testimonial at a time

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

```
  <?php $query = new WP_Query( 
         array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial' ,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
               ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
    <div class="testimonials-name"><?php the_title();?></div>
    <div class="testimonials-carousel-content"><p><?php the_content() ;?></p></div>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <!-- show pagination here -->
    <?php else : ?>

    <!-- show 404 error here -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I have this query but it display all the testimonial's I want it to display one testimonial at a time how to do this please help

I am not able to do this

Comment: Either rewrite the while loop to quit after the first iteration or only get one testimonial at a time

Comment: can you tell me how it can be done please

Comment: have you tried owl carousel?

Comment: no I didn't try that

Comment: jQuery('.testimonials-slider').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 800,
  minSlides: 1,
  maxSlides: 1,
  slideMargin: 32,
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});

Comment: I use bx slider only

Comment: http://www.programming-free.com/2013/01/responsive-rotating-testimonial-box.html, check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bxslider then you need to add the class that bxslider is targeting in to your html. Something like this:

```
<div class="testimonials-slider">
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
<div class="testimonials-name"><?php the_title();?></div>
<div class="testimonials-carousel-content"><p><?php the_content() ;?></p></div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>


<!-- show pagination here -->
<?php else : ?>

<!-- show 404 error here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No problem! Best of luck with future projects.

Comment: can you please tell me if we have to use 10 images in row inside slider then what I have to do

Comment: Have a look at the [bxslider examples](https://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions/). You just need to generate your html in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the bx slider in a right way, try the following code

```
<div class="testimonials-slider bxslider">
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial' , 'posts_per_page' => -1,) );

         if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
         <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
         <div class="testimonials-name"><?php the_title();?></div>
         <div class="testimonials-carousel-content"><p><?php the_content() ;?></p></div>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <!-- show pagination here -->
        <?php else : ?>

        <!-- show 404 error here -->
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {           
             $('.testimonials-slider').bxSlider({
                 mode: 'vertical',
                 slideMargin: 3,
                 auto:true
             });             
         });
    </script>
```